# attribute error- 'QuerySet' object has no attribute

Tags: python, django, modelform

i m trying to make an initialized form if my model object of a purticular user already exists but it is giving an attribute error

my views.py-

```
def edit_profile(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        post = request.POST
        if 'save' in post:
            form = user_profile_form(post)
            if form.is_valid():
                f = form.save(commit = False)
                f.username = request.session.get('username')
                f.save()
                return redirect('wall')
            else:
                return redirect('error')
    else:
        if 'username' in request.session:
            u = user_profile.objects.filter(username = request.session.get('username', ''))
            if u:
                form = user_profile_form(initial = {'last_name': u.last_name})
                u.delete()
            else:
                form = user_profile_form()
            return render(request, 'wall/edit_profile_page.html', {'form': form})
        else:
            return redirect('error')
```

and my models.py-

```
class user_profile(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length = 30, blank = True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length = 30, blank = True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length = 30, blank = True)
```

and it is giving error -

```
'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'last_name'
```

even if u exists

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Queryset is a "list" of objects.  You should get the first instance from the queryset using the `first()` method:

```
u = user_profile.objects.filter(username=request.session.get('username', '')) \
                        .first()
```

Comment: i just tried that using user_profile.get() and it worked..which is better..and what does .get() do??

Comment: In addition to the answer, you shouldn't search for an empty string when `username` is not found. There might be a user with an empty username in your table. Just use `request.session.get('username')`

Comment: If the record is not found then `get()` throws the `ObjectDoesNotExist` exception. `first()` in this case just returns `None`.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
try:
   u = user_profile.objects.get(username =request.session.get('username', None))
   form = user_profile_form(initial = {'last_name': u.last_name})
   u.delete()
except ObjectDoesNotExist:
   form = user_profile_form()
```